# Blazor InputFile component does not work when registering AutofacServiceProviderFactory

Tags: blazor, blazorinputfile

we can't able to upload the file in InputFile component when registering custom dependencies injection AutofacServiceProviderFactory. find the below code on Program.cs file.
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

please find the sample code below for your reference.

```
@using System
@using System.IO
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Upload Files
Max file size:

Max allowed files:

Upload up to @maxAllowedFiles of up to @maxFileSize bytes:

@if (isLoading)
{
Uploading...


}
else
{

@foreach (var file in loadedFiles)
{


Name: @file.Name

Last modified: @file.LastModified.ToString()

Size (bytes): @file.Size

Content type: @file.ContentType

}

}
@code {
private List loadedFiles = new();
private long maxFileSize = 1024 * 15;
private int maxAllowedFiles = 3;
private bool isLoading;

private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    isLoading = true;
    loadedFiles.Clear();

    foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
    {
        try
        {
            loadedFiles.Add(file);

            var trustedFileNameForFileStorage = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            var path = @"D:\" + file.Name;

            await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
            await file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File: {Filename} Error: {Error}",
                file.Name, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    isLoading = false;
}
}
```

Need to upload the file successfully.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

set `DisableImplicitFromServicesParameters` to true.

```
builder.Services
    .AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddHubOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.DisableImplicitFromServicesParameters = true;
    });
```

From here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38842#issuecomment-1342540950